# How do I make Network manager jump to higher priority network

Tags: ubuntu, raspberry-pi, networkmanager

Bassicly I have 2 networks "a" & "b". Network "a" has autoconnect priority of 5 and "b" a priority of 10. And autoconnect enabled on both.

Network "b" is a mobile hotspot so it's not always on. When the device boots it finds network "a". I find that it won't switch to network "b" automatically if it has an active connection to "a" already.

Is there a way to make network manager drop an active connection to Network "a" and connect to network "b" automatically if it's available?

This is a headless Raspberry PI running Ubuntu Server.

Comment: I have almost the opposite experience: every 30 seconds the high priority connection disconnects and then reconnects immediately, when I'd like it to stay where it already is.